# How to get char* with unknown length in C?

Tags: c, string, pointers

I have a C code like below:

```
char* text;
get(text); //or
scanf("%s",text);
```

But I try to run this it breaks. Because I did not give size for `text`.
Why I did not give a size for `text`, because i don't know what is the size of
text that user is going to enter. 
So, what can i do, in situations like this?
How can I read the text if I don't know the length of string?

Comment: use [getline](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/utopic/en/man3/getline.3.html)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can try this

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(void)
{
    char *s = malloc(1);
    printf("Enter a string: \t"); // It can be of any length
    int c;
    int i = 0;
    /* Read characters until found an EOF or newline character. */
    while((c = getchar()) != '\n' && c != EOF)
    {
        s[i++] = c;
        s = realloc(s, i+1); // Add space for another character to be read.
    }
    s[i] = '\0';  // Null terminate the string
    printf("Entered string: \t%s\n", s);  
    free(s);
    return 0;
}
```

**Note:** Never use `gets` function to read a string. It no longer exist in standard C.

Comment: Doesn't it depend on the architecture for the size of char? You have used malloc(1) instead of malloc(sizeof(char)).

Comment: @Kumar; If I remember, size of char is always `1` byte (though a byte is not necessarily of 8 bit on every architecture).